# Is there a way to get column headers available in multiple lines in a report file in Python?

Tags: python

Consider a tool generated report file use case.

A tabular data is available as plain text in the report file and I would like to parse through the report to  gather some data from the table and present in an html page.

```
Source   Arrival   Arrival   Departure   Departure   Destination
         Expected  Actual    Expected    Actual      
X        10:00     10:15     10:10       10:25       Z
A        8:30      8:30      8:45        8:50        B
```

Is it possible to get the exact column name by considering the two rows of header and then fetch value for the records?

Currently I had used crude way of setting flag to get the corresponding values from the required column

Comment: please show us what you've tried so far, and are there any constraints on the report file (for example no space or others)

Comment: Are you able to use other Python packages such as pandas?

Answer (score 1):

I would use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''Source   Arrival   Arrival   Departure   Departure   Destination
         Expected  Actual    Expected    Actual      
X        10:00     10:15     10:10       10:25       Z
A        8:30      8:30      8:45        8:50        B'''


df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(text), header=[0, 1])
# or from file
# df = pd.read_fwf('file.txt', header=[0, 1])

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda level: ' '.join([x for x in level if not x.startswith('Unnamed:')]))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Source Arrival Expected Arrival Actual Departure Expected Departure Actual Destination
0      X            10:00          10:15              10:10            10:25           Z
1      A             8:30           8:30               8:45             8:50           B
```

Comment: Did not know about read_fwf, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing about read_fwf. 
Is there any way to handle data which is not dumped fixed width in a report?

Comment: @Yadu of course, if you have a defined separator you can use `read_csv` instead